# Android App Stopped Working For No Reason

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

My android application literally decided not to work for no reason, I am going to go mad. I hope you can find the error. Please help me.

I opened the app on Virtual Device just one minute ago and noticed that I forgot to try one functionality, and tried to run it again but at the start of it, it gives me "GoogleSearch has stopped". I can post any activity you want. Here is the LogCat results:

```
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlesearch/com.example.googlesearch.Spash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at com.example.googlesearch.Spash.onCreate(Spash.java:18)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     ... 11 more
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     ... 23 more
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3328)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
05-22 12:47:29.179: E/AndroidRuntime(1952):     ... 26 more
```

**EDIT:** Here is the main activity's activity and layout.

```
public class Spash extends Activity {

    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 2000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.spash);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Spash.this, MainActivity.class);
                Spash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                Spash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/first_page"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT2:** Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlesearch"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"
        android:debuggable="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlesearch.Spash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlesearch.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PARENT_ACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.Spash" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlesearch.AuxilaryVerbs"
        android:label="@string/title_auxilary"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.googlesearch.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.googlesearch.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlesearch.Results"
        android:label="@string/title_result"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.googlesearch.AuxilaryVerbs" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.googlesearch.AuxilaryVerbs" />
        </activity>

        <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlesearch.InfoPage"
        android:label="@string/title_result"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.googlesearch.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.googlesearch.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlesearch.InternetPage"
        android:label="@string/title_result"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.googlesearch.Results" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.googlesearch.Results" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Don't you mention `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`?

Comment: plz also add layout xml which u are using for Fragment

Comment: devnull, is that mean the virtual devices memory or my computers? Because I have 8gb of available memory on my computer. How can I increase my Virtual Device's memory if it is caused by that? Because I set it to maximum already.

Comment: It means VirtalDevice not PC :). For increasing search the AVD creation tutorials.

Comment: Please post the layout xml and the manifest.

Comment: There was a inflate exception. Is the layout xml posted here, the xml specified in the setContentView() of your MainActivity class?

Comment: yogx, Yes it is, I also posted the activity. I will add the manifest right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I accidentally saved all PNG files 2667x4734 as my designer sent me. Therefore `devnull` is right, I scaled them down for my screen and it is working now. Thank you for everyone.